# How to apply code to multiple rows that satisfy a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet for scheduling tasks. I need to shade rows based on the value of one cell within that row.

I have code to carry out this function. I want to tweak the code to look at a number of different rows and carry out the same operation on each row, without me duplicating the code hundreds of times and just change the ranges.

With my code if E10 is equal to "Y" then it shades a range of cells in row 10 with "No Fill". Is it possible for the code to carry out the same operation on row 11 with cell E11 and row 12 with cell E12 etc.?

The code runs when a button is pressed.

The idea is, if a person is marked as here with a Y in the box, then their row is shaded white to allow planning of tasks in their row.

I tried conditional formatting but we need to shade certain cells when planning tasks and the conditional formatting overwrites it.

```vb
Sub Shade1()
    '
    ' Shade1 Macro
    '

    '
    If Range("E10").Value = "Y" Then
    
        Range("W10:AG10,AK10:BB10").Select
        Range("AK10").Activate
        With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Screenshot of Sheet
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop like:

```
Sub Shade1()
'
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String

    s1 = "E10"
    s2 = "W10:AG10,AK10:BB10"

    For i = 10 To 9999
        t1 = Replace(s1, "10", i)
        t2 = Replace(s2, "10", i)
        If Range(t1).Value = "Y" Then
            With Range(t2).Interior
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Make the **9999** whatever you need to cover all of your data.
There is no need to `Select` or `Activate`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. Can I ask is there an way to select a different colour if the specified value is "N" rather than "Y" within the same section of code?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [AutoFilter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) and avoid loops:

```
Sub Shade1()
    With Range("E8", Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)) ' reference column "E" cells from row 8 (header) down to last not empty one
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Y" ' filter referenced range with "Y" content
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then ' if any filtered cell other then header
            With Intersect(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow, Range("W:AG,AK:BB")).Interior ' reference intersection bewtween filtered range rows and columns W to AG and AK to BB
                .Pattern = xlNone
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False 'remove filtering
    End With
End Sub
```